# Let $a>0$, Show that $\int_{0}^{a} \ln(x) dx $ converges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

so when I calculated the improper integral I got, $$\int_{0}^{a} \ln(x) dx =[a\ln(a)]-a~,\qquad a>0$$ substituting as the limit goes from $a$ to $\infty$ I believe the integral diverges? I'm not sure what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: The $\lim_{x \to 0+} x \ln(x)$ is $0$.

Comment: ahhhh ok I see. However what do I do with the "$-a$"? do I do have to get the L'Hopitals of that as well? @Aaron

Comment: Perhaps the original question is asking about the convergence of the integral given a $fixed$ real number greater than zero. In that case, the integral converges.

Comment: Understood @FedePoncio

Comment: As $a\to \infty$ the integral obviously cannot converge, since the integrand is positive and increasing with $a \gt 1$.  A necessary (but not sufficient) requirement is the positive integrand $\to 0$.

Comment: Here you are supposed to show that the limit $$\lim\limits _{h\to 0^{+}}\int_{h}^{a}\log x\, dx$$ exists for any given $a>0$. The improper nature of integral is because of integrand $\log x\to-\infty $ as $x\to 0^{+}$.